# Do Apache Pig UDFs ever get called with null tuples?

Tags: apache-pig

https://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual

The example UDF has a null-check on the input tuple in the exec method. The various built-in methods sometimes do and sometimes don't.

Are there actually any cases where a Pig script will cause a UDF to be called with a null input tuple? Certainly an empty input tuple is normal and expected, or a tuple of one null value, but I've never the tuple itself be null.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple may be null because a previous UDF returns null.
Think on log analysis system, where you 1. parse the log, 2. enrich it with external data.

```
LOG --(PARSER)--> PARSED_LOG --(ENRICHENER)--> ENRICHED_LOG
```

If one log `LOG` have wrong format and cannot be parsed, the UDF `PARSED_LOG` may returns null. 
Therefore, if used directly, the `ENRICHENER` have to test the input.

You can `FILTER` those null values before too, specially if the tuples are used multiple times or `STORED`.

Comment: What does this look like in code? If I have a UDF `AlwaysNull`, and I call another UDF with the result of this, I'm still passing the 2nd UDF a tuple containing null, not a bare null.

Answer (score 0):

My best understanding after working with Pig for a while is that bare nulls are never passed bare nulls, always a non-null Tuple (which itself may contain nulls.)